# Protect voltage level translator from reverse voltage input

Tags: integrated-circuit, protection, reverse-polarity

I have a circuit that can interface with an external signal or power. And Those signal lines must be translated to a 3.3v level (and vice versa) because that what the circuit uses. And I would like to protect the the frontline IC from reverse input by the user

Although i have a [PMIC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2120.pdf?ts=1590344104209) power mux and is configured to protect against reverse inputs. The [voltage translator IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0108.pdf?ts=1590335668558) references the voltage before the PMIC. That is because IN1 of the PMIC either be present or not and if it is present it will have priority on the output, hence i reference the voltage translator on the output of the PMIC

Is it possible to also place a diode at the ground pin of the voltage translator just like the PMIC to protect it from RVP, Im afraid that since it does not have a direct reference to ground the signal voltages will be messed up

Another idea is to place a diode in series on input 2, But wont that cause a voltage drop on IN2?

[image]